# I want a global function which call on every button click in my whole application. What should be a short trick for this?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift

I want  a global function which call on every button click in my whole application. What should be a short trick for this?

I have tried many things like override add target method etc. button no luck yet. Let me know if i am unclear.

Comment: why voted down? Please explain in comments

Comment: Use `initWithCoder` and write `addTarget...` method there

Comment: This question does not seem to be completely meaningless to me, yet I'd want to hear more details like what is the intend and so on? The proper answer might depend on the details.

Comment: You can use **NsNotificationCenter** for multiple calls for single method

Answer (score 5):

This is a good question!

Just make an extension like this:

```
extension UIButton {

    override public func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        self.addTarget(self, action: #selector(methodTobeCalledEveryWhere), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
    }

    func methodTobeCalledEveryWhere () {
                print("HEY, I M EVERY WHERE!")

    }

}
```

Add this extension anywhere it should be in file scope though. 
It will make all the buttons in the the module (Module in which this extension resides)  trigger the method methodTobeCalledEveryWhere.

NOTE: This is for Swift 2.2

Comment: you need to swizzle awakeFromNib method in your extension with your custom awakeFromNib, otherwise you will only override UIButton's awakeFromNib with yours; you'll lose UIButton's awakeFromNib implementation completely.

Comment: But I have called super.awakeFromNib() won't that work?

Comment: in that case super.awakeFromNib is UIControl.awakeFromNib as this is an UIButton extension.

Comment: I just tried. awakeFromNib Seem to be added in an extension of NSObject. I am not too clear abt swizzling. Can you show me the code?

Answer (score 2):

you should write your own `UIButton` category/extension and you should **swizzle** [beginTrackingWithTouch:withEvent](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIControl_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIControl/beginTrackingWithTouch:withEvent:) method with your own method. When any `UIButton` instance calls its `beginTrackingWithTouch` method, your method will be called since you already swizzled it, thus you can perform any additional action every time a button is being tapped.

In fact `beginTrackingWithTouch:` is a `UIControl` method, so you can listen to all `UIControl` instances by writing your `UIControl` category/extension too.

A good read for more information about swizzling: http://nshipster.com/method-swizzling/

Comment: we have to swizzle only `sendAction:to:forEvent:` method for override action event.

Comment: i guess if you don't add target, it won't send action. as far as i understood, he wants to listen to all the tap actions regardless adding targets or not

Comment: yes you are right. i have updated my code. Thank you :)

Comment: well, i don't care about rep but you should at least cite me in your answer if you don't bother to edit and improve my answer. your welcome.

Answer (score 2):

In this type of problem you can use method swizzling. It is easy and best solution.
Following is `UIButton+SwizzleEvents` category. This category override `sendAction:to:forEvent:`. So every time button event execute, category method execute every time and you can execute your own code there.

`UIButton+SwizzleEvents.h`

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UIButton (SwizzleEvents)

@end
```

`UIButton+SwizzleEvents.m`

```
#import "UIButton+SwizzleEvents.h"
#import <objc/runtime.h>

void standard_swizzle(Class cls, SEL original, SEL replacement)
{
    Method originalMethod;
    if ((originalMethod = class_getClassMethod(cls, original))) { //selectors for classes take priority over instances should there be a -propertyName and +propertyName
        Method replacementMethod = class_getClassMethod(cls, replacement);
        method_exchangeImplementations(originalMethod, replacementMethod);  //because class methods are really just statics, there's no method hierarchy to preserve, so we can directly exchange IMPs
    } else {
        //get the replacement IMP
        //set the original IMP on the replacement selector
        //try to add the replacement IMP directly to the class on original selector
        //if it succeeds then we're all good (the original before was located on the superclass)
        //if it doesn't then that means an IMP is already there so we have to overwrite it
        IMP replacementImplementation = method_setImplementation(class_getInstanceMethod(cls, replacement), class_getMethodImplementation(cls, original));
        if (!class_addMethod(cls, original, replacementImplementation, method_getTypeEncoding(class_getInstanceMethod(cls, replacement)))) method_setImplementation(class_getInstanceMethod(cls, original), replacementImplementation);
    }
}

@implementation UIButton (SwizzleEvents)

+(void)load
{
    if (self == [UIButton class]) {
        static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
        dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
            NSArray *methods = @[@"beginTrackingWithTouch:withEvent:"];
            for (NSString* methodName in methods) {
                standard_swizzle(self, NSSelectorFromString(methodName), NSSelectorFromString([NSString stringWithFormat:@"new_%@", methodName]));
            }
        });
    }
}
-(BOOL)new_beginTrackingWithTouch:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    /*
     Put Your Custom Click Code Here
     (Execute befor your ibaction/action method call)
     */

    return [self new_beginTrackingWithTouch:touch withEvent:event];

    /*
     Put Your Custom Click Code Here
     (Execute after your ibaction/action method call)
     */
}
@end
```

If you want to use in whole application then you can import this category in pch file.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function in `AppDelegate` class and create a share instance of `AppDelegate` and you can that method from any class using that shared instance.

Answer (score 0):

first you declare a global function:

```
void yourfunction();
```

Implement it as:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "functions.h"
void yourfunction() 
{
  NSLog(@"global function is called");
}
```

You can call this method by using:

```
#import "functions.h"
yourfunction();
```

Hope it helps you

Answer (score 0):

> first make a global class and in that class you should make method. this method can be called from everywhere in whole app.